# Fast and persistable representation for filesystem-like data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'd like to have a persistable data structure and backing service (maybe, some kind of in-memory data grid, but with the ability to save data onto drives). The data that is going to be stored is almost identical in its structure to that of an ordinary filesystem - tree with variable number of children for each node (without complications like symlinks, though). There is some meta-information (payload) related to each node. What I basically need is to efficiently get all the branch in both directions (i.e. if I ask for all the parents of the node that has depth 1000, I'd like to have the same response time as if I asked for its closest parent or direct child). I'd like to have the ability to change node's position inside the tree (the position of all it's children as well, of course).

I know that Patricia trees are kinda good for my purposes, but the data isn't *actually* a filesystem, so there won't be any path with which I'd associate the node in the tree.

Minimal amount of stored data is ~100 million nodes, actual amount is expected to be at least 5-15 times of that.

Comment: you could model this in neo4j

Comment: @Justin, what about persistence?

Comment: @tom, I did that, but it appears to be unexpectedly slow. Especially when one has a broad and deep tree. How'd you implement the search for a node with the specified ID on depth ~10K and assuming each node has 100 direct children?

Comment: Neo attempts to keep the whole graph in memory, but that's a lot of nodes.  If you can't fit it in memory then it's going to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/)? It can act as an embedded, persisted graph database.

BTW You are likely to need significant amounts of memory.  I suspect you will need at least 100 - 1000 bytes per node if you want to keep it all in memory. i.e. up to 1 TB for 1 billion node.

If you don't have that much memory, you will need that much disk space and you will have to allow for the fact it will be many times slower.

Comment: Yes, we've already made that calculations. Amount of info per node is expected to be about 300 bytes, hence 1 billion nodes (without any other data needs something like 300GB of memory, and that's not an unexpected figure in this case.

Comment: You can buy boxes with 512 GB to 2 TB these days.  I would start with neo4j even if you decide later you want to write your own.  I suspect neo4j has a significant per-node/relationship overhead.

Comment: By the way, can't you tell if there is any way to use something like Hazelcast for the case? I know that there isn't (basically) any data structure with the desired capabilities, but can't I somehow reuse existing? I know that one can implement arbitrary distributed data structure using their SPI now, but the documentation is lacking and I can't find any suitable examples on that.

Comment: Yeah, the matter of overheads bothers me as well. And not only in terms of memory - as I told, I can't find a better way to find *the* child given a parent than to traverse *all* the outgoing relationships of the parent and that might be slow in the case of broad tree.

Comment: you can maintain the collection of children in the parent, the problem is this uses more memory.  Normally you can gain performance by using more memory but it doesn't sound like you have much to spare.

Answer (score 0):

A **tree of nodes** that contain the following things would probably fit your use case:

- Name
- Parent pointer
- HashMap (or sorted map) of Names -> child nodes
- Node level payload / metadata

This is enough to implement most filesystem-like traversal algorithms pretty efficiently.

Another alternative would be to consider an **immutable persistent data structure** - Immutability here would give you two big advantages:

- You you could store identical data / branches only once and potentially significantly reduce your memory requirement.
- Your data structure would be thread safe for efficient concurrent access, which is hard to achieve with mutable tree-like structures.

If you think the persistent data approach may be suitable, it is worth looking at Datomic (http://www.datomic.com/) which provides a database service for this kind of data.

Comment: But immutability doesn't play well alongside frequent changes being made to the tree, does it?

Comment: That's the difference between a persistent data structure and a regular immutable data structure. The persistent ones use structural sharing, so you don't need to take a full copy. This video is quite enlightening on the topic: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey